# Hyphenate [mediaqueries] as [media-queries]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Just another request to hyphenate a tag that consists of multiple words. This particular one is [mediaqueries](/questions/tagged/mediaqueries), which is rarely, if ever, encountered as a single word in writing. Should be [media-queries](/questions/tagged/media-queries). Probably with a synonym too if that's necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. I'm just announcing it to make sure I don't piss anyone off. Because, you know, retags are such a touchy topic and all.